# How to reference a layer provided by amazon for lambda function in serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Im trying to reference AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x:107 layer provided by amazon to my lambda function i tried hard coded the ARN but it doesn't work when deploying it on different stages.

I tried also this way but it also didn't  work.

layers:

- { Ref: MneLambdaLayer }
- AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x:107

Comment: What error do you encounter? Referencing via full ARN should be the way to go. What ARN are you using? Does the runtime Python version match the version the layer is built for?

Comment: You're correct I had a typo error in the arn it worked Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was hardcoded the ARN its the most correct way to do it simply i had a typo error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).